# Why am I getting this PHP error regarding HTML forms

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

This is the error message I am getting:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/content/50/8492150/html/colejoh/web/ai/form.php on line 10
```

For my HTML form I am using this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="form.php" method="post">
            Search: <input type="text" name="term" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <body OnLoad="document.myform.query.focus();">
    </body>
</html>
```

And for my form.php code:

```
<body>
   <?php
 $con = mysql_connect ("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "user", "password");
 mysql_select_db ("user", $con);

  if (!$con)
    { 
    die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
    } 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ai WHERE key LIKE $_POST["term"];") or die
        (mysql_error());

       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo 'ID: ' .$row['id'];
    echo '<br /> Key: ' .$row['key'];
    echo '<br /> Page: '.$row['page'];
  }

  mysql_close($con)
   ?>
     </body>
```

I believe the error is in the form.php in the sql statement at `LIKE $_POST["term"];")` What I am trying to do is to make that code to be what I submitted on the form page.

Comment: You're using quotes inside `$_POST["term"]`, as well as to delimit your string. PHP is seeing the first quote, and assuming that that terminates the string.

Comment: @andrewsi: that's actually the answer to the question, not a comment.

Answer (score 5):

This line is causing the problem:

```
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ai WHERE key LIKE $_POST["term"];") or die
```

Change it to:

```
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ai WHERE key LIKE " . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["term"]) . ";") or die
```

Also you should avoid using the `mysql_` functions they are deprecated.  Rather you should use `mysqli_` or PDO.  This code is also vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: it's not the "only way". `"SELECT ... $_POST[term];"` would work just as well, or `SELECT .. .{$_POST['term']};"` too.

Comment: **NO**. Don't post vulnerable code and go "oh, by the way". Put At the very least, `mysql_real_escape_string` in there. This is recklessly bad code.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry to sound like such a jerk, but a mistake like this could destroy a company or someone's career.

Answer (score 3):

You are not encoding the double quotes correctly.  Change the $sql assignment to

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ai WHERE key LIKE '".mysql_real_escapse_string($_POST["term"])."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

This will also guard you from sql injections.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ai 
                 WHERE key LIKE '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['term'])."'") 
                or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should not post your mysql username and password.

Second of all, The search term should be quoted.

Comment: Although technically valid, your answer doesn't contain any example code, where there are a number of others here that do. Wherever possible, try and include some code to demonstrate what you're talking about, especially if you can adapt what was posted originally.

Answer (score 0):

In php you have to be very careful when working on string variables. To connect multiple string variables you should do it like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM ai WHERE key LIKE" . $_POST["term"] . ";"
```

To make your life easier, you should often create "helper" variables like this:

```
$my_variable="SELECT * FROM ai WHERE key LIKE" . $_POST["term"] . ";"
```

And then add it to your script like so:

```
$sql = mysql_query($my_variable) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Escaping is not optional. This snippet of code is extremely dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

`$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ai WHERE key LIKE 'mysql_real_escapse_string($_POST[term])'");`

Update the above query.

There should not be any double quotes for term

Comment: Without escaping, this is extremely dangerous.

Comment: Yes agreed I just wanted to highlight double quotes for term. MySQL itself is not recommended at 1st place.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<body>
   <?php
 $con = mysql_connect ("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "user", "password");
 mysql_select_db ("user", $con);

  if (!$con)
    { 
    die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
    } 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ai WHERE key LIKE ".$_POST["term"].";") or die
        (mysql_error());

       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo 'ID: ' .$row['id'];
    echo '<br /> Key: ' .$row['key'];
    echo '<br /> Page: '.$row['page'];
  }

  mysql_close($con)
   ?>
     </body>
```

Comment: You cannot put `$_POST` in a query without escaping.

Comment: I know, but that wasn't the purpose of the question!

Comment: The purpose of the question is to get the code working *correctly*. Having a massive SQL injection bug is **not** correct. Please take these things more seriously.

Answer (score -1):

Replace your line error by this one :

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ai WHERE key LIKE $_POST[\"term\"];") or die
    (mysql_error());
```

Comment: You cannot put `$_POST` in a query without escaping.